# jQuery function triggered multiple times on same click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a function for a rating system on my website http://broadcasted.tv/.
It can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Ee5G/

It's a form inside a tip which adds and removes ratings. Hhowever on my website (example page http://broadcasted.tv/show/47/arrested-development/) when I score a show in the tips (at the bottom of the page), six requests are sent at the same time and I don't understand why (I'm new to jQuery)

For those who want to see the requests on the website, I've created a test account there:

username: stackoverflowhelp
password: testtest

Here's the part of the function which has the ajax call

```
$(".showscoreupqtip").click(function () {
    var button = $(this);

    if ($(button).hasClass("removeshowscoreqtipup")) {
        var show_id = button.siblings(".show_id").val();
        var user_id = button.siblings(".user_id").val();
        var score = $('input[name="tvshowrating-' + show_id + '"]:checked').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/showscoreajaxremove.php",
            data: {
                "show_id": show_id,
                    "user_id": user_id,
                    "score": score //we are passing the name value in URL
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    } else {
        var show_id = button.siblings(".show_id").val();
        var user_id = button.siblings(".user_id").val();
        var score = $('input[name="tvshowrating-' + show_id + '"]:checked').val();

        if (show_id == '') {
            $('#show_id').addClass('error');
            return;
        } else {
            button.removeClass('error');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/showscoreajax.php",
                data: {
                    "show_id": show_id,
                        "user_id": user_id,
                        "score": score
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    button.val('Scored');
                    button.addClass('success');
                    button.addClass('removeshowscoreqtipup');
                    button.removeClass('addshowscoreinqtip ');
                    if (data !== 'error') {
                        $('#up-' + show_id).replaceWith('<div class="rating-recent-text">' + data + '</div>');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Edit: (the whole function)

```
$(function () {

$('.tip-tvshow').each(function () {
    var tipContent = $(this).next('.tip-content').clone();
    $(this).qtip({
        content: tipContent,
        prerender: 'true',
        show: {
            ready: 'true',
        },
        hide: 'mouseout',
        position: {
            adjust: {
                method: 'flip'
            },
            my: 'bottom middle', // Position my top left...
            at: 'top middle', // at the bottom right of...
            target: $(this) // my target

        },
        viewport: $(window),
        style: {
            classes: 'mytip',
            tip: {
                corner: true,
                mimic: false,
                method: true,
                width: 18,
                height: 8,
                border: 1,
                offset: 0,
            }
        },
        events: {
            render: function () {

                $('.tvshowrating').submit(function () {
                    $('.test', this).html('');
                    $('input', this).each(function () {
                        if (this.checked) $('.test', this.form).append('' + this.name + ': ' + this.value + '<br/>');
                    });
                    return false;
                });




                $(".showscoreupqtip").click(function () {


                    var button = $(this);

                    if ($(button).hasClass("removeshowscoreqtipup")) {
                        var show_id = button.siblings(".show_id").val();
                        var user_id = button.siblings(".user_id").val();
                        var score = $('input[name="tvshowrating-' + show_id + '"]:checked').val();


                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/showscoreajaxremove.php",
                            data: {
                                "show_id": show_id,
                                    "user_id": user_id,
                                    "score": score //we are passing the name value in URL
                            },
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data) {

                                location.reload();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {


                        var show_id = button.siblings(".show_id").val();
                        var user_id = button.siblings(".user_id").val();
                        var score = $('input[name="tvshowrating-' + show_id + '"]:checked').val();

                        if (show_id == '') {

                            $('#show_id').addClass('error');
                            return;
                        } else {
                            button.removeClass('error');

                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "/showscoreajax.php",
                                data: {
                                    "show_id": show_id,
                                        "user_id": user_id,
                                        "score": score
                                },
                                cache: false,
                                success: function (data) {

                                    button.val('Scored');
                                    button.addClass('success');
                                    button.addClass('removeshowscoreqtipup');
                                    button.removeClass('addshowscoreinqtip ');
                                    if (data !== 'error') {
                                        $('#up-' + show_id).replaceWith('<div class="rating-recent-text">' + data + '</div>');
                                    }


                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });

                $('.hover-star').rating({
                    focus: function (value, link) {
                        // 'this' is the hidden form element holding the current value
                        // 'value' is the value selected
                        // 'element' points to the link element that received the click.
                        var tip = $('#hover-test');
                        tip[0].data = tip[0].data || tip.html();
                        tip.html(link.title || 'value: ' + value);
                    },
                    blur: function (value, link) {
                        var tip = $('#hover-test');
                        $('#hover-test').html(tip[0].data || '');
                    }
                });

            },
        },
        hide: {
            when: 'unfocus',
            fixed: true
        },
        show: {
            when: 'mouseover',
            solo: true // Only show one tooltip at a time
        },
    });
});
```

});

Comment: most likely said code is executing more than once.

Comment: I figure it's been executed the same number of time the class .showscoreupqtip exists, it's the why that I don't have

Comment: You have an `each` loop that is assigning a new click event each time it runs. These will all run in a chain in the order they were added. You need to re-think how that click function is bound.

Comment: @asawyer What are some of the other ways I should look at ?

Comment: Why does it need to be in the each loop?

Comment: Because there are multiple tips with different content ? Does it not need to be ? @asawyer

Comment: You've posted gobs of unrelated code so it's hard to see right off. You should always aim for the smallest reproducible example when posting questions. At a glance, I see nothing in the click event related to the specific loop iteration, so again, why does it need to be in the loop?

Comment: @asawyer I picked this up from another member on stackoverflow before I could understand jQuery at all.... I thought it needed to be because each tip has different content. Is it not the case ? What other options do  I have ?

Comment: I don't even see a loop.

Comment: @KevinB That's at the beginning of the whole function there http://jsfiddle.net/4Ee5G/

Comment: Why isn't that part of your question? it's very relevant.

Comment: @KevinB It is there, second line! "I have a function for a rating system on my website http://broadcasted.tv/. It can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Ee5G/ "

Comment: Right, but what happens when your site is fixed, or jsfiddle is down. (your question becomes useless to future visitors) The only thing relevant to your question is `$(selector).each(function(){ ... $(anotherselector).click(function(){ ... });});` the error is within those two lines.

Comment: To fix the error though, we'll need to know how `selector` and `anotherselector` relate to each other.

Comment: I added the whole function. What can I replace the each function with ?

Comment: There is a .showscoreupqtip inside every .tip-tvshow @KevinB

Comment: Then your `anotherselector` (in reference to my previous comment) should be `$(".showscoreupqtip",this)` so that it only targets the one inside the currently being iterated element.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks Kevin, would never have figured that out by myself. I'm guessing it specifies which it's a click on this specific tip.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Exactly, it's essentially the same as `$(this).find(".showscoreupqtip")`

Comment: Check if you need to unbind previous handlers.